# Is it fundamentally impossible to have passive thunderbolt to dual-link-DVI or HDMI adapter supporting 2560x1440?

Tags: hdmi, resolution, thunderbolt-display, dvi

Is it fundamentally impossible to have a passive (NOT the expensive USB-powered active ones) thunderbolt/mini-displayport to dual-link-DVI or HDMI adapter that can support 2560x1440 external monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Not only is this not impossible, but [products that do this exist](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010U28E32). DisplayPort (and therefore mini-displayport and thunderbolt) supports DVI and HDMI output over passive adapters using [Dual-mode DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode).  Dual-mode DisplayPort only supports single-link DVI or HDMI. Single-link DVI is limited to 1900x1200, but single-link HDMI can go up to 2560x1600@60Hz with HDMI 1.3+, and bigger on new HDMI versions. In the DisplayPort 1.1 spec, [VESA introduced](http://www.displayport.org/pr/vesa-introduces-updated-dual-mode-standard-for-higher-resolution-interoperability-with-hdmi-displays/) a spec for dual-mode DisplayPort to support HDMI 1.4 output, using "Type 2" adapters.

Comment: Thanks. Is what you mentioned true for Thunderbolt 1 as well or it needs Thunderbolt 2? Because all the passive Thunderbolt to HDMI cables i see that mention support above 1920x1200 also mention Thunderbolt 2 specifically.